# Explain this regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression in java:

```
'String'.replaceAll("([aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn1234567890])\\1+", "$1")
```

Can someone explain what the different characters do?

Comment: Perhaps a regex tutorial would be a good first step? Or some experimentation on any of the online regex evaluators? Some are even graphical and help break things down.

Comment: I know what a regex is but i don't get all of it, specifically the \\1+ part

Comment: regular-expressions.info

Comment: You realise that if you just hover over the regex tag that you created and click info, all the "info" you need is right there?

or : http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: (In fairness, it looks like a few other people could also benefit from a refresher course.)

Comment: Also, weirdest almost-`[a-z0-9]` regex ever; h, l, and r are missing. I don't get it. This still bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

- `[aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn1234567890]` Matches a single character in the list.
- `([aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn1234567890])` Capturing group around the char class would capture that single character.
- `\1+` `\1` is a pointer to refer the chars inside the group index 1. In our case, a single character is captured so it refers to that single character. `\1+` means one or more occurrences of the characters inside group index 1.

**For Example:**

```
aaaa
```

The above regex would capture the first character and check if the following one or more characters  are same as the first character which was captured. If yes, then the whole duplicated chars are replaced by a single char(which was inside group index 1 ), that is `aaaa` was replaced by a single `a`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/8)

Answer (score -3):

All letters that are listed between brackets will be replaced by $1 if after them comes a \1, which is a literal backslash one. The plus sign (+) means 1 or more.

Answer (score -3):

Any sequence of 1 or more of the characters inside the brackets [...] will be replaced with $1.

For instance, this will remove all those characters from your string:
System.out.println(Str.replaceAll("([aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn1234567890])\1+", ""));